# What does T superscript mean in control systems and estimators? (ARMAX)

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares

We are studying ARMAX models in my Stochastic Adaptive Control course and for the life of me, I can not figure out what this represents, though it seems to be very significant. Here's a picture for context:

[image]

Comment: Could it be a matrix of dimensions equal to the number of inputs to the system?

Comment: Matrix transpose?

Comment: You hav linked to a page of a document that is three chapters (sections?) in.  There is a ton of missing context.  What document is this?  What do the previous sections cover?  What is $\phi$? What is $y_k$? Please edit your question to address this issues.

Comment: @XanderHenderson It is pretty obvious that $\phi_k^T$ is the transpose of $\phi_k$, here. No need for further clarifications.

Comment: @amsmath It is not even clear to me that $\phi$ is a matrix.  While I agree that it is almost certainly true, the question doesn't provide enough context to be sure.  $T$ could also represent a time index (such notation sometimes occurs in the study of dynamical systems).

Comment: @XanderHenderson I completely disagree. Read the text. They write something like "inverse of $\sum\phi_k\phi_k^T$ exists". I mean, what more do you want...

Comment: $\phi^T\theta$ denotes the dot product of the vectors $\phi$ and $\theta$. You can think of this as matrix multiplication since $\phi^T$ is $1\times n$ and $\theta$ is $n\times 1$, so the result is $1\times 1$ (a scalar). But $\phi_k\phi_k^T$ on the other hand would be $n\times n$ matrix.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix $A = (a_{ij})_{i,j=1}^{m,n}$, then $A^T$ denotes its transpose $A^T = (a_{ji})_{i,j=1}^{n,m}$. For example,
$$
\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\3&4\\5&6\end{pmatrix}^T = \begin{pmatrix}1&3&5\\2&4&6\end{pmatrix}.
$$